# Multimedia preview not updated?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We have an eventsystem with a Save/Initiated (oncomponentsavepre) event where thumbnail images are created from the multimedia component that is being saved.

The new thumbnail multimedia component is then added as a multimedialink in the metadata of the image component that is being passed in the event.

Whenever the image is updated in the original compnent, the thumbnail is being updated as well with a new thumbnail image.

There is a minor issue after opening the multimedia component however. I would expect the metadata showing a preview of the newly created thumbnail in the multimedia link. But what you see is a preview of the previous thumbnail component instead.

Does anyone know how I can update the multimedia link preview as well?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're doing it in this way rather than resizing the image at publish time, e.g. using the resizer TBB?

Comment: Good question, the client still have a lot of legacy applications/component templates (vbscript, I know.. it's old) that rely on the thumbnail components. They will be replaced eventually by compound templates, but for now it will have to do with the thumbnails components in the original image components.

Comment: Fair enough, was just curious :)

Comment: What happens when you try to save the thumbnail to local disk, do you get the new version saved?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov Opening and saving the thumbnail works fine. I can save the image to disk and I get the image created through the event system. 

The problem seems only to appear on the small preview of the componentlink to this thumbnail component. Because this is something new in 2011 I suspect this is a bug. I think I'll create an issue for SDL to take a look at this.

Comment: Could there be something in your thumbnail image itself that prevents Tridion from scaling it down to the small preview size? Just clutching at straws here, I must admit..

Comment: Did you try clearing the browser cache?

Comment: I've tested some things now. And it seems the multimedialink preview (generated by /WebUI/Editors/CME/icon.png) doesn't get updated when you upload a new image into an existing multimedia component. Does anybody know where the generated preview images are saved and how this gets invalidated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed by support that it's actually a bug. And there is a hotfix for this problem:
CM_2011.1.1.80564 on the sdltridionworld site will handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is working as expected, it is just the preview inside SDL Tridion?

Could this just be the caching in the component dialog?   If you hit f5, does it give the correct preview image?  I typically have to hit f5 after i've changed a schema to get the updated fields etc.

I'm looking if there is a way to turn off this caching (I can't find it yet) but in the extreme case  you could probably create an extension to force this image to refresh, I've also seen there is a good document online from SDL :  [debugging the CME gui @ SDL TridionWorld.com](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Debugging_the_Tridion_2011_CME.aspx).

Comment: I tried hard refreshing it and opened it in a different browser, but no luck. The image URL for the multimedia link preview at http://test.yamnet.com/WebUI/Editors/CME/icon.png?URI=tcm:98-506740&mode=thumb&maxwidth=100&maxheight=100 doesn't update.